# Prime factorization correspondence in simple extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

This is exercise 6.8 of Falko, Algebra I. I think I solved most part of the problem but I still have some saddle points to handle.

Let $f,g$ be irreducible polynomials over $K$ field both without repeated roots in algebraic closure of $K$.  $L=K(a),E=K(b)$ be the extension with $f(a)=g(b)=0$. Show if $f=\prod f_i,g=\prod g_i$ are prime factorizations over $K(b),K(a)$ respectively, we have $r=s$, and after reordering we have $E[x]/f_i\cong L[x]/g_i$. In particular $[K(b):K]deg(f_i)=[K(a):K]deg(g_i)$.

The first thing to notice is $K(a)[x]/(g)=\frac{K[y][x]}{(f,g)}=K(b)[x]/(f)$. The result is basically based on chinese remainder theorem and identification of minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K(b)$ and $b$ over $K(a)$ respectively. Since $K(a,b)=L(b)=E(a)$, I can remove the $K(a,b)$ part only from the product of $K-$algebras which are $E[x]/(f)\cong \prod_iE[x]/(f_i)$. Then induction on $r$ of $\prod_{ i\leq r}E[x]/(f_i)\cong\prod_{j\leq s} L[x]/(g_i)$ where I assumed that minimal polynomials of $a,b$ in $K(b)[x],K(a)[x]$ are $f_i,g_i$ respectively.

1. Is there any straightforward way to do this problem?
2. What I am doing here is too Ad Hoc? Any particular reason why I need to perform each step? Say I am telling a story and my story is quite unpleasant.
3. What is this problem telling me here? What is the context or what is $E[x]/(f)$?
4. The non-repeated roots here removed the multiplicity issue here. Will I still somehow maintain the isomorphism/ structure if I remove no-repeated roots condition?

Comment: What are $r$ and $s$? I can make an educated guess, but do tell us :-)

Comment: I guess that at some point you invoked (or proved?) that if $L_1\oplus L_2\oplus\cdots\oplus L_r$ and $E_1\oplus E_2\oplus\cdots\oplus E_s$ are direct sums of finite extensions of $K$ such that they are isomorphic as $K$-algebras, then, up to a permutation, $L_i\simeq E_i$. If you lift the separability assumption, then something may go wrong (for one thing you don't usually get a direct sum of fields, because CRT fails).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for late response. r and s are number of prime factorizations of f and g resepctively. Since I have no repeated roots over algebraic closure, the direct summand each is a field. The equality of $\oplus L_i=\oplus E_i$ allows projection to isomorphic objects. I could just use induction on n along with $\oplus_{i\leq r} L_i=\oplus_{i\leq s} E_i$ with $r\leq n$. The exercise is due to Dedekind according to the author of the textbooks. What is the reason considering $E[x]/(f_i)=K[x,y]/(f(x),g(y))$ for the study? For what kind of algebraic or geometric settings?